# some problems of numOfRows method in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

this is my UITableViewDateSource code:

```
#import "TableViewDataSource.h"


@implementation TableViewDataSource

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableCell;
@synthesize LHfetchedResultsController;
@synthesize numberOfRows;
@synthesize dataTemp;
@synthesize paused;

-(id)initWithTableView:(UITableView *) tableView
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView = tableView;
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)dateSourceWithChineseNewestVideosFetchedResultsController
{
    self.tableCell = [TableCellModel getCellOfFreeChampionsList];
    [self setChineseNewestVideosLHFetchedResultsController];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self configCellData:indexPath cell:self.tableCell];

    // Configure the cell with data from the managed object.
    return self.tableCell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[self.LHfetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.LHfetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        self.numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

//        return self.numberOfRows;
        return 1;
    } else
        return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.LHfetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
-(void)configCellData:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath cell:(id)cell
{
    NSLog(@"DataSourceTempCount is %lu",(unsigned long)self.dataTemp.count);
//    NSInteger indexNum = indexPath.row;
//    ChineseNewestVideos * Video = [self.dataTemp objectAtIndex:indexNum];
    ChineseNewestVideos * Video = [self.LHfetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextView * textView = [self.tableCell viewWithTag:11];
    textView.text = Video.title;

    UILabel * la = [self.tableCell viewWithTag:12];
    la.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Data Count is %lu",(unsigned long)self.numberOfRows];
    if (indexPath.row %2 == 0) {

        self.tableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else
    {
        self.tableCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    }
}

-(void)setLHFetchedResultsController:(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    self.LHfetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController;
    self.LHfetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    NSError * err;
    if (![self.LHfetchedResultsController performFetch:&err]) {
        //启动
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error : %@, %@",err,[err userInfo]);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

-(void)setChineseNewestVideosLHFetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSFetchRequest * request = [ChineseNewestVideos fetchRequest];
    NSEntityDescription * testEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ChineseNewestVideos" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    request.entity = testEntity;
    NSSortDescriptor * sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"createdate" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
//    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSFetchedResultsController * ChineseNewestVideosLHFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    [self setLHFetchedResultsController:ChineseNewestVideosLHFetchedResultsController];
}
```

TableView is a property of ViewController
data has no problem, but display of table has problem
start from `-(void)setChineseNewestVideosLHFetchedResultsController`

when i set different return of `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`, display is different
like this:

when return 1
[when return one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sjHw.png)

when return 2
[when return two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjWyz.png)

when return 3
[when return three][3]

when return 4 or more
[when return four or more][4]

display always like this,and when i drop up, the textview will suddenly disappear
who know what happen?

Comment: [link]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VqcY.png
  [link]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQz7a.png

Comment: here is when i change return to 3 or 4 or more

Comment: Why is there no dequeue of cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init every cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` thats why there is only one tableview cell. You need to "create" cell for each row. So put that method in the

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
    TableCellModel *cell = [TableCellModel getCellOfFreeChampionsList];
    [self configCellData:indexPath cell:self.tableCell];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Fixed it thank u bro it is so simple and so hard haha